# Objective-C custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get the error:

> VertexPoint.m:12:1: Type of property 'color' ('GLfloat *' (aka 'float
>   *')) does not match type of instance variable '_color' ('float [4]')

and

> VertexPoint.m:12:1: Type of property 'position' ('GLfloat *' (aka
>   'float *')) does not match type of instance variable '_position'
>   ('float [3]')

What should i do to resolve it?

Here is the code:

```
//
//  VertexPoint.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "VertexPoint.h"

@implementation VertexPoint

- (id)init {
     self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _position[0] = 1;
        _position[1] = 2;
        _position[2] = 3;

        _color[0] = 1;
        _color[1] = 2;
        _color[2] = 3;
        _color[3] = 4;
    }
    return self;

};

- (GLfloat *)x {
    return &_position[0];
};
- (GLfloat *)y {
    return &_position[1];
};
- (GLfloat *)z {
    return &_position[2];
};
- (GLfloat *)r {
    return &_color[0];
};
- (GLfloat *)g {
    return &_color[1];
};
- (GLfloat *)b {
    return &_color[2];
};
- (GLfloat *)a {
    return &_color[3];
};

- (void)setPosition:(GLfloat *)pos {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        _position[i] = pos[i];
};
- (void)setColor:(GLfloat *)col{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        _color[i] = col[i];
};

@end
```

and

```
//  VertexPoint.h
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>

@interface VertexPoint : NSObject
{
    GLfloat _position[3];
    GLfloat _color[4];
}
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *position;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *color;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *x;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *y;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *z;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *r;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *g;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *b;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *a;

- (GLfloat *)x;
- (GLfloat *)y;
- (GLfloat *)z;
- (GLfloat *)r;
- (GLfloat *)g;
- (GLfloat *)b;
- (GLfloat *)a;
-(void)setColor:(GLfloat *)col;
-(void)setPosition:(GLfloat *)pos;
@end
```

**UPDATED AGAIN (2)**

The new h and m files:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>

@interface VertexPoint : NSObject
{
    GLfloat _position[3];
    GLfloat _color[4];
}
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *position;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) GLfloat *color;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) GLfloat x;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) GLfloat y;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) GLfloat z;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) GLfloat r;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) GLfloat g;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) GLfloat b;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) GLfloat a;

- (GLfloat)x;
- (GLfloat)y;
- (GLfloat)z;
- (GLfloat)r;
- (GLfloat)g;
- (GLfloat)b;
- (GLfloat)a;
-(void)setColor:(GLfloat *)col;
-(void)setPosition:(GLfloat *)pos;
@end
```

and

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "VertexPoint.h"

@implementation VertexPoint

- (id)init {
     self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _position[0] = 1.0f;
        _position[1] = 1.0f;
        _position[2] = 1.0f;

        _color[0] = 1.0f;
        _color[1] = 1.0f;
        _color[2] = 1.0f;
        _color[3] = 1.0f;
    }
    return self;

};

- (GLfloat)x {
    return _position[0];
};
- (GLfloat)y {
    return _position[1];
};
- (GLfloat)z {
    return _position[2];
};
- (GLfloat)r {
    return _color[0];
};
- (GLfloat )g {
    return _color[1];
};
- (GLfloat )b {
    return _color[2];
};
- (GLfloat )a {
    return _color[3];
};

- (void)setPosition:(GLfloat *)pos {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        _position[i] = pos[i];
};
- (void)setColor:(GLfloat *)col{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        _color[i] = col[i];
};

@end
```

The original error message is still there.

Comment: Why are all of your `GLfloat` properties defined as pointers? `GLfloat` is a simple primitive type.

Comment: shouldn't they? This is the first time i have to do something like this please teach me :)

Comment: When it says "does not match type of instance variable '_color' ('float [4]')" and " does not match type of instance variable '_position' ('float [3]')" it's upset because you are trying to replace a float with a pointer to a float. All those asterisks are probably not necessary when declaring and returning a GLfloat. If you need to use pointers, go ahead and do so. But you can't replace a float with a float pointer and pretend they're the same data type.

Comment: Learn the difference between a pointer and an array.  (Hint:  The difference is entirely fictional, but the compiler likes to be lied to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
- (GLfloat *)color {
    return &_color[0];
}

- (GLfloat *)position {
    return &_position[0];
}
```

to your .m implementation file.

What's happening is that you've declared properties for `color` and `position` with types `GLfloat *`, and you have instance variables called `_color` and `_position`. The compiler wants to link these together automatically through the standard property-ivar naming convention, but these mismatch in types (the compiler is complaining because a float pointer and an array of floats aren't the same thing for these purposes; you can't return an array in C.)

If you *explicitly* add getter methods that correspond to the properties, then you can provide the mapping (and different typing) explicitly yourself, as I've shown here. In these two cases, I've returned simply the pointer to the first element in the array. The caller in these cases will have to simply know that the color array has four elements and the position one has three.

Comment: Except that one should not be passing floats around by pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks: Why do you say that? There are certainly other ways to design the OP's vertex point class, but I don't understand a blanket interdiction like you seem to be making. (Please provide context, especially if you downvoted. Thanks.)

Comment: A guy who doesn't know what he's doing should not be passing floats by pointer.  That should be patently obvious.  There are situations where it might be appropriate, but not when you don't even understand what a pointer is.

Comment: @HotLicks: You can only coach one thing at a time, and it's unrealistic to bring all questioners to expert status on every detail of what they ask about. (S)he also didn't understand properties and their interaction with instance variables, which was the proximate cause of their troubles. This answer addresses the question (s)he actually asked, with an explanation that was apparently found useful. I understand and respect your opinion, but I think the comment is heavy-handed.

Comment: Sorry I am a Java, Android developer so this objective-c and pointers and everything is new for me and when everything is new I can write stupid code... Thanks for helping!